# Constant symbols in a binary

Tags: c, assembly, macros, gnu

If my program does a

```
#ifdef USE_REL_DEF
#  define MAX_NUM_REL 10
#else
#  define MAX_NUM_REL 5
#endif
```

Is it possible to inspect the generated binary to know the final value of MAX_NUM_REL ? I dont have the option of putting a log/print in the program, but I do have the generated binaries.

I tried with nm and objdump, but no luck finding the value of the symbol.

Comment: #define by itself doesn't directly let a trace into the binary. Defines are replaced with their respective values (10 or 5) where they appear in the code at compile time.

Comment: These symbols are going away even before the compilation starts, on the preprocessing phase.

Comment: You _might_ find that in the debugging symbols, depending on your environment and build settings.

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to inspect the final value of `MAX_NUM_REL` that way: this is not a variable but a placeholder that will be replaced by the value you defined just before the actual compilation of your code (during the *preprocessing* phase).

The only thing you can control is the consequence of using it:

For example, should you have the following line somewhere in your C code:

```
 int myIntegerVariable = MAX_NUM_REL;
```

- You can either see the value that is actually used by running the preprocessor (just the preprocessor, not the compiler) on your code: this will produced another C file with `MAX_NUM_REL` replaced by its actual value (`int myIntegerVariable = 5;`). You have to refer to the documentation of the compiler you are using to see how to run the preprocessor on a file.
- or you can dissassemble your compiled code to determine whether 10 or 5 was used in that place. This is not easy though.

  - The symbol `myIntegerVariable` will not appear as such in the binary code. This is a symbol that you will only be able to track if you compiled your program with the debug option that keeps a symbols table available in the binary.
  - And even with the symbol table, this is not something you can detect at first glance, this requires some work.
- And finally, even if you can't produce log, you can do step-by-step debugging of your code normally. This allows you to inspect the variable or function parameters that are set to `MAX_NUM_REL` in your code.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to inspect the generated binary to know the final value of MAX_NUM_REL?

No, at least not directly.  `MAX_NUM_REL` is a *macro*, not a variable.  The preprocessor replaces the macro name with its expansion (whichever that is) everywhere that it appears as a preprocessing token within the scope of the macro definition.  If it appears anywhere where it is not a complete preprocessing token then that cannot be as the name of an object.

If there happened to be a file-scope variable somewhere in the binary that is initialized with the value of `MAX_NUM_REL`, such as ...

```
int num_rel = MAX_NUM_REL;
```

... then you could find the initial value for that symbol in the binary, and deduce the chosen value of `MAX_NUM_REL` from that.

It might also be possible to use the preprocessor to formulate an educated guess about which definition is used.  Suppose that the file containing that definitions is `mysource.c`.  If you are able to invoke the preprocessor with all of the same options that are used for the actual compilation, then preprocessing this source ...

```
include "mysource.c"

int the_value = MAX_NUM_REL;
```

... with those same options<sup>*</sup> will (probably) produce a bunch of pre-processed C source ending with either

```
int the_value = 5;
```

or

```
int the_value = 10;
```

Be aware that this might not give you the correct answer if `MAX_NUM_REL` is re-defined somewhere in the source, but that's something you can check for easily enough.

How you run only the preprocessor depends on your system.  If you're using `gcc` then you can use `gcc -E`.

<sup>*</sup>You may need an extra option to ensure that `mysource.c` is in the include search path.

Answer (score 0):

That's not actually a symbol. If you were trying to search for `MAX_NUM_REL`, that's no good since this is a `#define` which means that it's not even a variable because all the work is done by the preprocessor (so this exact name doesn't go into the binary file).

To find this value you need to have the source code and then see where this define is used and only after that search for the name of a variable this value is assigned to.